# Can a type declaration be made in a Switch statement?

Tags: iphone, ios4, switch-statement

I am using XCode 4.0.2 for a iOS4 project.

I have a standard "Switch" statement

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        int a = 0;
    break
    ...
}
```

This give me an error "Expected expression" on int a = 0;.

It is very strange that "Switch" is working fine if I precede type declaration with a simple statement like this

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        b = 0;
        int a = 0;
    break
    ...
}
```

in this case the compiler gives no error (only a "unused variable a" warning).

How can that be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
    {
        int a = 0;
    }
    break
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose the case statement in curly brackets:

```
switch (i) {
    case 0: {
        int a = 0;
        break; 
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to open a new scope with `{ }` in order to declare new variables:

```
switch (i) {
    case 0: {
        int a = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables like

```
switch (i) {
    case 0:
        { //User brackets 
            int a = 0;
        }
    break
    ...
}
```